# turning on Greasemonkey live editing

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey, userscripts

On Firefox, I click Tools, Addons, Extensions, Greasemonkey, Options, select my user script, click Edit, change the source code, click save, reload one of the included pages, but the script is the unchanged version.

On User Scripts, logged in, I click my username, Script Management, my script's name, Admin, Edit Code Online, change the source code, click save, the link to the install page, install and the script is the changed version.

How did you turn on Live Editing? While following Greasemonkey tutorials, this feature is not working... Are you going to use the "works on my computer" excuse? Should this be on the Stack Overflow sister site Super User?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! It's here: http://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual:Editing

Greasemonkey has to edit the copy of the original script that is in the Firefox profile folder. To make Greasemonkey do that, you have to move the original script to the Recycle Bin, because then it'll prompt for the script location again and then you'll be able to select the copy of the original script that is in the Firefox profile folder.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that in the UserScripts section, you specifically click "Save", while in the Greasemonkey section, you don't.  Greasemonkey can't run your modified script until you've saved it back to disk so that Greasemonkey can reload it.

Comment: Before amending the question, I was already clicking save. Thanks for noticing the mistake.